# How to change the CSS after image lazy loading (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, css, image, loading, lazy-evaluation

I've got the following problem: after the user clicks on a thumbnail image, a bigger image is loaded with lazy loading and opens up. The code to load the bigger image is:

```
<img width="663" height="845" class="big" data-original="real/path/to/image" src="path/to/empty/small/picture">
```

When the user clicks on a thumbnail image, the following code is executed:

```
$("img.thumb").click(function() 
 {      
    var $cont = $(this).siblings('.item-content').children('.big'); 
    $cont.attr('src', $cont.attr("data-original"));
    setTimeout(function(){
        $cont.css({'height': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
    }, 600);
 });
```

Each big image has to have the CSS `"height"` set to `"auto"`, and the `"width"` set to `"100%"` because I am making a responsive/fluid layout. The above code gets its `"src"` attribute value from the `"data-original"` attribute. But `"height: auto"` and `"width:100%"` are set in this example to `600ms` after the attributes do their replacing. This doesn't work, because I am using Isotope jQuery plugin (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) for this and this plugin needs the real width and height of the element to position the grid properly. When `"height: auto"` and `"width:100%"` are set during the loading of an image, the plugin gets lost and makes positions the elements incorrectly.

So how do code this to set those 2 CSS properties after the image has loaded?

Comment: maybe wait until plugin does it's stuff and then set dimensions?

Comment: @Linas - I guess you're right. However, the job done by plugin is based on dimensions. But you gave me some ideas - there is a function in that plugin - `$container.isotope('reLayout');` - which relayouts the whole grid. So it would work, if I could execute it after the image is loaded. The problem is that I don't know how to define when the image has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution: there is a small jQuery plugin, called [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded). It triggers a callback after all the selected child images have been loaded. The problem was that you can't do `.load()` on cached images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.load()`

```
$('img.big').load(function() {
    if($(this).attr('src') == $(this).attr('data-original')) {
        $(this).css({'height': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TYufy/4/ - example using `.load()`

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. I am wondering - is replacing attributes treated as "loading", since "img.big" exist in code from the beginning?

Comment: yes, it should be treated as loading. When you change the `src` of an img, the browser needs to load it. Updated answer with JS fiddle.. image changes after 1 sec